# Implementing Referenceable objects client-side with Twisted Perspective Broker

Tags: python, twisted, perspective, broker

I am trying to implement a simple server reply in Perspective Broker.

Possible implementation (please suggest others if possible):

Client requests server to execute a server method, Server executes then replies (by executing a client method whose sole purpose is to print a message):

```
[Client-side]:

class ClientPrint(pb.Referenceable):
    def remote_clientprint(self, message):
        print "Printing the message from the server: ", message

[Server-side]:

class RootServerObject(pb.Root):
    def remote_OneFunc(self, ...):
        ...
        print "Now sending the reply..."
       *get ClientPrint object?*
       clientprintobj.callRemote("clientprint", "this is the reply!")
```

How can I implement the grabbing of client-side objects? Is there a better way to implement server replies than grabbing a client-side object and calling a print-only client method?

Here is the full code where I am trying to implement the replies:

[Client-side]:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.spread import pb

class Client():
    def __init__(self, addr, port, spec):
        self.addr = None
        self.port = None
        self.SomeData = None

    def connect(self, addr, port):
        factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP(addr, port, factory)
        def1 = factory.getRootObject()
        def1.addCallbacks(self.got_obj, self.err_obj)

    def got_obj(self, rootsrvobj):
        print "Got root server obj:", rootsrvobj
        self.server = rootsrvobj
        def2 = self.server.callRemote("SomeFunc", SomeData)

    def err_obj(self, reason):
        print "Error getting root server obj:", reason
        self.quit()

def cmdsub(addr, port, SomeData):
    c = Client(addr, port, SomeData)
    c.connect(addr, port)
```

[Server-side]:

```
class RootServerObject(pb.Root):
    def __init__(self):
        self.DataOut = None

    def remote_SomeFunc(self, SomeData):
        self.DataOut = hash(SomeData)
        print "Now sending reply..."
        *implement a reply?*
```

Perhaps there are some more advanced Twisted (or Twisted PB) features that will make this simpler.

Documentation: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/pb-usage.html#auto3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to take the client-side object that the server needs to use and pass it to the server.  Almost any solution I can think of has this at its core.

Change your client's `got_obj` method to be something more like this:

```
def got_obj(self, rootsrvobj):
    print "Got root server obj:", rootsrvobj
    self.server = rootsrvobj
    def2 = self.server.callRemote("SomeFunc", self, SomeData)
```

And change the implementation of `remote_SomeFunc` to be something more like this:

```
def remote_SomeFunc(self, client, SomeData):
    self.DataOut = hash(SomeData)
    print "Now sending reply..."
    client.callRemote("client_print", "Here is your reply")
```

You might want to investigate [Twisted Cred](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/cred.html) as a more structured way to manage references to your client object - but cred is just building on this exact feature of Perspective Broker to provide its more abstract, more featureful interface.

However, notice that I said "almost" above...

Keep in mind that Twisted's implementation of Perspective Broker has well-integrated support for Deferreds.  If a `remote_` method returns a `Deferred` then no response will be sent to the method call until the `Deferred` fires and then the result will be sent as the result of the method call.  You might consider putting the logic of `client_print` into a *callback* on the `Deferred` returned by `self.server.callRemote("SomeFunc", SomeData)` and making the server's `remote_SomeFunc` *return* the reply, either synchronously or asynchronously (as a `Deferred`).